# How can I find a middle element in a linked list?

Tags: data-structures

How can I find a middle element in a linked list by traversing the entire list only once?

The length of the list is not given, and I am allowed to only use two pointers. How can this be done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't see how you could do it without traversing the entire list unless you know the length.

I'm guessing the answer wants one pointer to be traversing one element at a time, while the second pointer moves 2 elements at a time.
This way when the second pointer reaches the end, the first pointer will be at the middle.

Comment: BUT I want to whether it works for both odd and even number of elements in a link list... ?

Comment: Try it out on paper for 1,2,3,4,5 elements - you'll notice a pattern and how/why it works

Answer (score 12):

The below code will help you get the middle element.
You need to use two pointers "fast" and "slow". At every step the fast pointer will increment by two and slower will increment by one. When the list will end the slow pointer will be at the middle.

Let us consider the `Node` looks like this

```
class Node
{
  int data;
  Node next;
}
```

And LinkedList has a getter method to provide the head of the linked list

```
public Node getHead()
{
  return this.head;
}
```

The below method will get the middle element of the list (Without knowing the size of the list)

```
public int getMiddleElement(LinkedList l)
{
    return getMiddleElement(l.getHead());
}

private int getMiddleElement(Node n)
{
    Node slow = n;
    Node fast = n;

    while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null)
    {
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }

    return slow.data;
}
```

**Example:**
If the list is 1-2-3-4-5 the middle element is 3
If the list is 1-2-3-4 the middle element is 3

Answer (score 2):

In C, using pointers, for completeness. Note that this is based on the "[Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_cycle-finding_algorithm#Tortoise_and_hare)" algorithm used for checking if a linked list contains a cycle.

Our node is defined as the following:

```
typedef struct node {
    int          val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;
```

Then our algorithm is thus:

```
node_t *
list_middle (node_t *root)
{
    node_t *tort = root;
    node_t *hare = root;

    while (hare != NULL && hare->next != NULL) {
        tort = tort->next;
        hare = hare->next->next;
    }

    return (tort);
}
```

For a list with an even number of nodes this returns the node proceding the actual centre (e.g. in a list of 10 nodes, this will return node 6).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers one for odd and one for even, both having the same algorithm

For odd: One pointer moves one step and second pointer moves two element as a time and when the second elements reach the last element, the element at which the first pointer is, the mid element. Very easy for odd.
Try: 1 2 3 4 5

For even: Same, One pointer moves one step and second pointer moves two element as a time and when the second elements cannot jump to next element, the element at which the first pointer is, the mid element.
Try: 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList.Node current = head;
  int length = 0;
  LinkedList.Node middle = head;

  while(current.next() != null){
      length++;
      if(length%2 ==0){
          middle = middle.next();
      }
      current = current.next();
  }

  if(length%2 == 1){
      middle = middle.next();
  }

  System.out.println("length of LinkedList: " + length);
  System.out.println("middle element of LinkedList : " + middle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a size variable you can maintain the size of the Linked list.

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node headnode;
    private int size;


    public void add(int i) {
        Node node = new Node(i);
        node.nextNode = headnode;

        headnode = node;
        size++;
    }

    public void findMiddleNode(LinkedList linkedList, int middle) {
        Node headnode = linkedList.getHeadnode();
        int count = -1;
        while (headnode != null) {
            count++;

            if(count == middle) {
                System.out.println(headnode.data);
            }else {
                headnode = headnode.nextNode;
            }

        }
    }

    private class Node {
        private Node nextNode;
        private int data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.nextNode = null;
        }
    }

    public Node getHeadnode() {
        return headnode;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Then from a client method find the middle of the size of the list:

```
public class MainLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
        linkedList.add(5);
        linkedList.add(3);
        linkedList.add(9);
        linkedList.add(4);
        linkedList.add(7);
        linkedList.add(99);
        linkedList.add(34);
        linkedList.add(798);
        linkedList.add(45);
        linkedList.add(99);
        linkedList.add(46);
        linkedList.add(22);
        linkedList.add(22);

        System.out.println(linkedList.getSize());

        int middle = linkedList.getSize()/2;

        linkedList.findMiddleNode(linkedList, middle);
    }
}
```

I don’t know if this is better than the two node way, but here also you don’t have to traverse through the entire loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# to find a middle element of the linked list:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LinkedList<int> linked = new LinkedList<int>();
    linked.AddLast(1);
    linked.AddLast(3);
    linked.AddLast(5);
    linked.AddLast(6);
    linked.AddFirst(12);

    Console.WriteLine("Middle Element - " + ListMiddle<int>(linked));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static T ListMiddle<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    if (input == null)
        return default(T);

    var slow = input.GetEnumerator();
    var fast = input.GetEnumerator();

    while (slow.MoveNext())
    {
        if (fast.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!fast.MoveNext())
                return slow.Current;
        }
        else
        {
            return slow.Current;
        }
    }
    return slow.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below Java methods finds the middle of a linked list. It uses two pointers:

1. Slow pointers which moves by one in each iteration.
2. A fast pointer which moves twice in each iteration.

The slow pointer will point to the middle when fast reaches the end of the list

```
public SinglyLinkedListNode getMiddle(SinglyLinkedListNode list) {

    if (list == null)
        return null;

    SinglyLinkedListNode fastPtr = list.next;
    SinglyLinkedListNode slowPtr = list;

    while (fastPtr != null) {
        fastPtr = fastPtr.next;
        if (fastPtr != null) {
            slowPtr = slowPtr.next;
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next;
        }
    }

    return slowPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a doubly-linked list with given pointers to the head and tail node:

We can use both head and tail traversal:

```
p = head;
q = tail;
while(p != q && p->next != q)
{
    p = p->next;
    q = q->prev;
}
return p;
```

Introducing a pointer to the middle node may be an option, but functions like insertNode and deleteNode have to modify this pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Python code for a middle element using the two-pointer method:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next

    def insertAtBeg(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def findMiddle(self):
        fast_ptr = self.head
        slow_ptr = self.head

        if(self.head is not None):
            while(fast_ptr is not None and fast_ptr.next is not None):
                fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next
                slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next
            print('The middle element is ' + str (slow_ptr.data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylist = LinkedList()
    mylist.insertAtBeg(10)
    mylist.insertAtBeg(20)
    mylist.insertAtBeg(30)
    mylist.findMiddle()
```

Output:

> The middle element is

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
        linkedList.add(10);
        linkedList.add(32);
        linkedList.add(90);
        linkedList.add(43);
        linkedList.add(70);
        linkedList.add(20);
        linkedList.add(45);

        int middle = linkedList.size()/2;
        System.out.println(linkedList.get(middle));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my solution which will work for both odd and even number of elements scenarios like:

- 1-2-3-4-5 middle element 3
- 1-2-3-4 middle element 2,3

It is inspired by the same fast pointer and slow pointer principle as mentioned in some of the other answers in the post.

```
public class linkedlist {

    Node head;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d)  { data = d; next=null; }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        linkedlist ll = new linkedlist();
        Node one = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(3);
        Node fourth = new Node(4);
        Node five = new Node(5);
        Node sixth = new Node(6);
        Node seventh = new Node(7);
        Node eight = new Node(8);
        ll.head = one;
        one.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;
        fourth.next = five;
        five.next = sixth;
        sixth.next = seventh;
        seventh.next = eight;
        ll.printList();
        ll.middleElement();
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node n = head;
        while(n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.data + "  ---> ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public void middleElement() {
        Node headPointer = head;
        Node headFasterPointer = head;
        int counter = 0;

        if(head != null) {
            while(headFasterPointer.next != null) {

                if(headFasterPointer.next.next != null) {
                    headFasterPointer = headFasterPointer.next.next;
                    headPointer = headPointer.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    headFasterPointer = headFasterPointer.next;
                }
                counter++;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The value of counter is " + counter);
            if(counter %2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("The middle element is " + headPointer.data + "," + headPointer.next.data);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The middle element is " + headPointer.data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class Node:

```
# Function to initialise the node object

def __init__(self, data):

    self.data = data

    self.next = None
```

Class LinkedList:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.head = None


def push(self, new_data):

    new_node = Node(new_data)

    new_node.next = self.head

    self.head = new_node


# Function to get the middle of
# the linked list

def printMiddle(self):

    slow_ptr = self.head

    fast_ptr = self.head

    if self.head is not None:

        while (fast_ptr is not None and fast_ptr.next is not None):

            fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next

            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next

        print("The middle element is: ", slow_ptr.data)
```

#### Driver code

```
list1 = LinkedList()

list1.push(5)

list1.push(4)

list1.push(2)

list1.push(3)

list1.push(1)
list1.printMiddle()
```

Comment: What programming language? [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score -2):

It's stupid to use two pointers, "fast" and "slow", because the operator next is used 1.5n times. There is no optimization.

Using a pointer to save the middle element can help you:

```
list* find_mid_1(list* ptr)
{
    list *p_s1 = ptr, *p_s2 = ptr;
    while (p_s2=p_s2->get_next())
    {
        p_s2 = p_s2->get_next();
        if (!p_s2)
            break;
        p_s1 = p_s1->get_next();
    }
    return p_s1;
}
```