# Extract middle element from a single linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I have a question:

> Find the middle element from a single linked list.

I need to know the way/method of this problem.

Comment: Great - what is your question ?

Comment: lol. this is the question!

Comment: No, it's a *statement* - you have said that you have a problem - you haven't asked for anything specific, e.g. do you just want hints, or an algorithm, code in some programming language or other, a complete working solution mailed directly to your teacher, or what ? Please take a minute to read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: well... as I am new in stack overflow so ...

Comment: Sure - so take the [2 minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and maybe read some of the online help - it looks like a number of your previous questions have been down-voted due to low quality - you can improve your questions and your response rate by reading the online help and looking at some of the up-voted questions on the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find a middle element in a link list without traversing the entire list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446355/how-to-find-a-middle-element-in-a-link-list-without-traversing-the-entire-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two pointers to iterate through the list - one which iterates twice as fast as the other. When the fast pointer reaches the end of the list then the slow pointer will be pointing at the mid-point.

Algorithm:

```
init slow_pointer = head
init fast_pointer = head
repeat
   fast_pointer = fast_pointer->next;
   if fast_pointer == NULL
      break;
   fast_pointer = fast_pointer->next;
   if fast_pointer == NULL
      break;
   slow_pointer = slow_pointer->next;
until false
// slow_pointer now points at the middle node
```

Comment: can you explain your logic behind the algorithm .. i can't understand

Comment: Read the first paragraph to get an overview, then look at the algorithm description in detail.

Comment: hmm.. i understood that through this method one can get the middle item but why faster is twice than slower ptr? any other way??

Comment: It sounds like you need to think about it some more - maybe sketch out on paper step by step what happens in the algorithm for a short list - consider also what happens when the length of the list is odd or even, or when the list is empty.

Comment: @PaulR really cool solution! Quick question; are we assuming that we don't know the length of the linked list? Isn't it standard for a linked list to know its size?

Comment: @PaulR the reason I ask this is because why can't we just iterate through the link list 1/2 the size?

Comment: @NickZuber: yes, if you know the size of the list then it's a trivial matter to get to the mid point. Often though you don't know the length - maintaining the length requires additional book-keeping and this can have a performance/complexity cost.